# HttpClient PostAsync() doesn't work while POSTMAN works fine

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, postman

I'm trying to post an item on my Azure database account. I wrote and published to the Azure account an ASP.Net Core web application, which implements such methods as Get, Post, Put, and Delete. On my Xamarin Forms project, I'm trying to call HttpClient PostAsync method to create(post) a record in the Azure database. Testing the same transaction on POSTMAN works just fine, but it doesn't work in my Xamarin Forms mobile app. The GetStringAsync method works just fine both on POSTMAN and on my mobile app. I have no idea why the PostAync only doesn't work. Please help!

Here's the event handler method where PostAsync is called:

```
async void OnAdd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This item is to be posted to the Azure database.
    var tblmoney_item = new TblMoney
    {
        RecordDate = Convert.ToDateTime("7-26-2020"),
        ItemDesc = "coffee",
        AmountOut = 4500,    // The currency unit is in KRW. (KRW 4,500 = US$4).
        SpentTypeId = 3
    };

    // Serialize the item in JSON format.
    var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tblmoney_item);

    // POST the item to the URL. Works fine on POSTMAN, but does NOT work on my mobile app.
    await _client.PostAsync(Url, new StringContent(content));
    
    // Refresh the list view.
    _tblmoney_items.Insert(0, tblmoney_item);
}
```

Here's the declaration within the MainPage class of the variables(properties) above:

```
private const string Url = "https://testwebapi.azurewebsites.net/tblmoney";
private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
private ObservableCollection<TblMoney> _tblmoney_items;
```

The item's Class desclaration is as the following:

```
public partial class TblMoney
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RecordDate { get; set; }
    public string ItemDesc { get; set; }
    public int? AmountOut { get; set; }
    public int? SpentTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual TblSpentType SpentType { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the Controller Class in the REST Web API project, which is an ASP.Net Core Web Application project.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[Produces("application/json")]

public class TblMoneyController : ControllerBase
{
    private mynotedbContext _context = new mynotedbContext();

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<TblMoney> Get()
    {
        // get all tblMoney items.
        return _context.TblMoney.ToList();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]TblMoney tblmoney_item)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _context.TblMoney.Add(tblmoney_item);
        _context.SaveChanges(true);
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status201Created);
    }
}
```

The DB context looks like this:

```
public partial class mynotedbContext : DbContext
{
    public mynotedbContext()
    {
    }

    public mynotedbContext(DbContextOptions<mynotedbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<TblMoney> TblMoney { get; set; }
...
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: At what point is failure occurring? a. The post method is not being hit at all? b. The method hits but fails at the `ModelState.IsValid` or c. Somewhere around the `_context`

Comment: What’s not working?

Comment: My first guess would be that the Content-Type header doesn't seem to be set ("application/json").. you could set the header on the client or look at `new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))`.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the first request with Postman and c#.  Make the c# look like postman.  The default headers in c# is different from Postman.

Comment: @CaiusJard That was the problem! It now works perfectly. Thanks so much. You made my day.

Comment: @jdweng I'll be sure to check out wireshark or fiddler for future debugging. Good info. Thanks so much.

Comment: I wasn't getting any exception (before taking care of the issue). The content type header wasn't set as "application/json" and it remained silent while a new record didn't get posted. I re-wrote the part as **new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")**, and it did the magic. Thanks so much for those who cared to leave comments.

Comment: @sgk151 Reposted comment as answer so you can mark it off if you like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(From comments)

I recommend you set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` - you can either do this as setting the header on the client or by using the overload of stringcontent that declares the type: e.g. `new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))`